# Cloudformation list IAM Policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-iam

Can you dynamically list IAM Polices as a drop down menu within the Cloudformation options? 
The usual use case for this is adding instance types to a drop down. This is written manually though in all examples I have seen and is not dynamically created as an instance type is not an AWS resource.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot at this time.  It is not a supported [AWS-Specific Parameter Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types)